# SQL Server 2016 Plugin's not working

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016, windows-10, plugins

Recently I installed SQL Server 2016 on my PC.

Here is the detailed information of my server :

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RC1) - 13.0.1200.242 (X64)
>   Mar 10 2016 16:49:45
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>   Enterprise Evaluation Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3  (Build 10586: )

After installing server on my PC then tried to install the below plugin's

1. [SQL Pretty Printer Add-In for SSMS V3.6.1](http://www.dpriver.com/dlaction.php)
2. [SQLSentry Plan explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view)

Problems:

1. **SQL Pretty Printer** does not even install it was throwing error like

   [image]

   But the **SQL Pretty Printer** site says it works on SQL Server 2016 you can check the link.

   [image]
2. Next **SQLSentry Plan explorer** was installed successfully but the plugin was not showing up in `SSMS`.

**Version:** v2.8 (Build 9.0.9252.0)

[image]

Can anyone help me out with this thing. Note both worked perfectly in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because these bugs should be reported to the vendor and this version of SQL Server 2016 is still beta software

Comment: SQL Server 2016 RC2 is out already : )

Comment: Annnnd, it's RTM as of June 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vendors will need to catch up, as the add-in model and API have changed. This will lead to better extensibility, but for now you'll need to wait for the vendors to do this work. There is usually not much advantage to doing all of that work while the product is still in beta and the add-in model is still changing (the version of SSMS released on Friday is on a completely different VS shell and is radically different, which vendors knew would happen, and that would have rendered any work done against earlier RCs and CTPs a waste).

Please wait for RTM before expecting all vendors to have perfect integration. If you need these add-ins in the meantime, keep a supported version of SSMS installed too.

Or, in the case of Plan Explorer, use a simple workaround - all our add-in really does is provide a shortcut to right-clicking a plan, saving as .sqlplan, and then double-clicking in file explorer or using file/open in Plan Explorer. Or better yet, generate actual plans inside Plan Explorer, where you get much more useful metrics anyway.